# Why is vapor from boiling pots hot while vapor caused by air is not?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, energy-conservation, matter

So when we boil water, the resultant vapor (steam) is hot. But when water is evaporated by air or by atomization, the vapor is cool?!

Both water's have absorbed energy from the surroundings and thus have become gas, but one is hot, the other isn't? Am I missing something?

Comment: Why would the temperature of water that is exposed to a large volume of air, say at room temperature, rise to 100 degrees celsius?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Not the water. I'm talking about the temperature of the steam/vapor, not the liquid water.

Answer (score 3):

[image: boiling water]
boiling water ($\color{red}{\blacksquare}$=liquid water,
$\color{red}{\bullet}$=water molecule,
$\color{blue}{\bullet}$=air molecule)

Consider a pot with boiling water.
The space above the liquid water surface is filled with
hot water steam (i.e. fast water molecules flying around).
These fast water molecules collide with each other only,
and therefore don't loose their kinetic energy.
Only in the region where hot steam and cold air mix,
the fast water molecules can loose their excess kinetic energy
to the slower air molecules, i.e. the hot steam cools down only there.

---

[image: evaporating water]
evaporating water ($\color{red}{\blacksquare}$=liquid water,
$\color{red}{\bullet}$=water molecule,
$\color{blue}{\bullet}$=air molecule)

Now consider the pot with moderately warm water slowly evaporating.
Only a few fast water molecules leave the liqid water surface,
initially with about the same high speed as in the boiling picture.
But the fast water molecules are mixed with many more
slow air molecules. Therefore, by collisions the water molecules
quickly loose their excess kinetic to the air molecules.

Comment: What about when it is evaporated when atomized? Is the vapor resulting from atomization hot? Since there is a huge concentration of water molecules near the atomized "drops" compared to air molecules.

Answer (score 1):

The steam from a boiling pot is exposed to 100 deg C water while the "steam" from normal evaporation is exposed to approximately 25 deg C air.  The steam from both sources has the temperature of the process that generated it.

Note that there is a difference between heat and temperature.  It takes approximately the same amount of heat transfer to vaporize 1 kg of water at 100 deg C as it does to evaporate 1 kg of 25 deg C water.  That heat transfer represents a transfer of energy, while the temperature of the resulting steam represents how "concentrated" its internal energy is.